# Dependencies gradle com erro

Tags: android

Toda vez que tento introduzir qualquer API no meu projeto e vou colocar o compile lá no dependencies do gradle ele dá erro e não sai disso.

Já tentei sincronizar também.

O gradle só volta a funcionar se eu tiro a API que eu acabo de colocar. No caso estou tentando colocar uma API que deixa as imagens com moldura em cículo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código:

**Build.gradle (Módulo)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "E**DITADO**"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'


}
```

**Build.gradle (Aplicação)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        }



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: se voce tem essa API voce tem de ter ela na sua pasta "../app/libs", para isso se vc tá usando o android studio, va em "project estructure/app" e na guia dependencies adicione ela clicando em mais e escolha a opção "file dependecies", se naum funfar me avisa que a jenta tenta resolver

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho, eu coloquei a pasta da API no local onde você me disse. Coloquei a linha lá no dependencies do gradle, sincronizei e o aplicativo rodou certinho. 

Porém mesmo assim, lá no gradle fica as 3 linhas em vermelhos, como na imagem acima. Posso ignorar ?

Comment: No caso ele não precisa ter a biblioteca, visto que ele está utilizando a dependência pelo Maven. Você colocou o mouse em cima para ver o erro?

Comment: @VitorHenrique Tentei rodar agora e apareceu o mesmo erro no gradle. Como na imagem acima.

Comment: verificou se o gradle não está offline? 
Tive um problema semelhante (com outra lib) por causa disso. 
Verifique em CONFIGURAÇÕES -> BUILD -> GRADLE se tiver marcado como offline, desmarque e reinicie o AS

Comment: @MarcelaMelo Verifiquei agora e a opção Global Gradle Settings > Offline work está desmarcado. =\

Comment: Verifique se está adicionado: `repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}` no seu `build.gradle`

Comment: Verifique também no seu outro `build.gradle` (o que é referente ao seu projeto) se tem `allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}`

Comment: @VitorHenrique coloquei a imagem na pergunta. Está tudo correto.

Comment: Coloque seus dois `build.gradle`completo, mas copie e cole aqui e insira eles dentro da tag de código pra gente analisar melhor.

Comment: @VitorHenrique Não consigo colocar o código aqui. Excede o limite. Preferes que eu coloque ali na minha pergunta ?

Comment: Isso, edite e coloque na pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei, mas ficou bem desconfigurado. Usei a tag de código e mesmo assim ficou deste jeito.

Comment: tenta fazer assim ó:
cria um projeto novo com uma activity em branco e v se ele roda, se rodar, voce apaga o build.gradle desse seu projeto e copia o conteudo do build.gradle desse novo projeto nele, dai vc vai adicionando as dependencias passo a passo, se der problema, tenta atualizar o seu SDK

Comment: Se seu código do build.gradle esta igual o que você postou ali, remova a aparição da linha: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']), pois está duplicada, deixe somente a primeira.

Comment: Acho que encontrei o erro vou postar como resposta.

Comment: @BrunoRomualdo Removi, e dá o mesmo erro. Vou tentar criar um projeto novo, como o Armando comentou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu `Build.gradle (Aplicação)` pegue a linha `maven`:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
   repositories {
       maven { // Essa linha
          url "https://jitpack.io" // Essa linha
       } // Essa linha
   }
}
```

E mova logo abaixo para:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven { // Coloque aqui
           url "https://jitpack.io"
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: antes de realizar este procedimento, fiz um backup do meu projeto, voltei para tentar fazer o que você disse. E realmente deu certo. Obrigado